# Put an image on an exact position

Tags: html, css

I have an image (it is a map pointer https://goo.gl/RPo9qm ) and I want to put it on the exact place on the map using CSS, so it would stay on the position on the map why scrolling. 
I cannot add the pointer and the map to the same image because there will be some animation with the pointer. 
How would you do that?

Edit: map is an image as well

Answer (score 1):

Simply position your Map image and the Pin using `position:absolute;`

Here's an example with a **draggable Pin**:

```js
$('#pin').draggable({
  containment: "parent"
});
```

```css
#mapContainer{
  height:300px;
  position:relative; /* set to relative in order to contain absolute child elements */
  overflow:auto;     /* make scrollable! */
}
#map{
  position:absolute; /* absolute map! */
}
#pin{
  position:absolute; /* absolute pin! */
  width:50px;
  margin-left:-25px;
  left:337px;
  top:144px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="mapContainer">

  <img id="map" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/4789V.gif">
  <img id="pin" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/SionM.png">

</div>
```

P.S: HTML order (map → pin) matters, otherwise you'll end up having your Map overlaying the Pin.

Comment: You do not have to have this order in your HTML if you use `z-index` in CSS.

Comment: @anroesti exactly, but since using `z-index` is almost exactly like using `!important` (sign of poor markup) ... let's use them only when really needed.

Comment: @RokoCBuljan Agreed. Just figured I'd add that info for anyone who cannot change their markup.